# When does a background task get aborted because of "ResourceRevocation", and how do I prevent it?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile

I'm working on an UWP (Win10) app that needs to maintain a persistent Rfcomm connection to a bluetooth accessory.

Seemingly at random, the OS decides to kill off the background task. The cancellation reason is "ResourceRevocation".

What are the conditions for a ResourceRevocation to occur, and how do I prevent it?

I've tried switching background task type (RfcommTrigger / DeviceUseTrigger), but they all get killed by the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The detailed information about resource revocation is not disclosed I believe. In my experience, to avoid the revocation, we should reduce the usage of resources from our background task , or, reduce the OTHER app's one.

In my case, the default settings of Win10M background apps - ALL of apps can use the background task - prevent the running of my background task. In this case, my task is aborted with resourcerevocation, or just not called. To resolve this, I should disable the unnecessary background task usages by apps - photos, office apps, etc - from settings > Privacy > Background Apps. Then, my bgtask works well. Perhaps this is not a suitable answer for you, but I wish that it helps you.